# Where, if anywhere, does CUPS save the file of a printed document?

Tags: command-line, printing, directory, metadata

I want to create a document management system where I can get the file location of each printed document from the print job history of cups. But I can't find a way to retrieve this information.

I already tried

```
lpstat -W completed
```

but it only gives me the job id, user, timestamp etc but no information about the origin of the file. In my case the directory and the file name.

Does anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `cups-files.conf`

> **RequestRoot directory**
>
> Specifies the directory that contains print jobs and other HTTP request data. The default is "/var/spool/cups".

Files are saved in a format:

```
/var/spool/cups/d*-nnn
/var/spool/cups/c*
```

where

- `*` is the printer id.
- `c` is the control file
- `d` is the actual data
- `nnn` is the document number. Starts with 001.

Oh and see if you have 'testipp' installed. It is a cups utility that will spit out everything you even need to know about the document

---

This gives a list of completed jobs ([taken from U+L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123634/how-to-show-the-cups-printer-jobs-history)):

```
sudo lpstat -W completed -u $(strings /var/spool/cups/* | \
grep -A 1 job-originating-user-name | \
grep -oP '.*(?=B)' |sort -u | paste -sd ',')
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Very appriciated! I found in the `cups-files.conf` a path to another file called `/var/log/syslog` where the file path of printed files are logged. Unfortunately, the string of the path is limited to a certain size, which cuts a part of the path of at the end. `/home/username/example/project/filename.pdf` becomes `/home/username/example/proje` for example. I'm going to look more into this and maybe i find something better or i have to work around that. But it's definitely a start in the right direction!

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` is a standard logging facility. Only use that for scanning for errors that need fixing. In case you ever go public with your document management system ... it does not need to exist and other linux will use /var/log/messages.

Comment: Oh i see. Ok i will look for another solution.

Comment: How about `/var/log/cups/page_log`? Oh and the command I added is nifty too No directory but this assumes /var/spool/cups ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the terminal command :) I've tried it but it's not working yet. I looked in the `/var/spool/cups` folder and i'm missing the page_log file. I'm guessing my page_log output is currently written in the syslog file.

Comment: It says in `man conf-files.conf` that the page log gets put into the page_log, standard error log or syslog. I guess changing it to page_log will help ...

Comment: /var/spool/cups > cat c01197 | strings

Comment: I have noticed that sadly not all apps store the file info to /var/spool/cups/* Libreoffice does but xnviewmp doesnt

Comment: But that was not the question ;-) The question was "where does cups store files". if xnviewmp does not use cups it will use another printer backend (there are many and it could even have its own backend).